# ENOENT Error While Setting Up Hyperledger Explorer V1.1.2

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

Did anyone integrated HL Explorer V1.1.2 with HL Fabric 2.1. While I tried to setup the Explorer V1.1.2 with Fabric 2.1 it is giving the ENOENT error for some of the packages which I believe it should not be if we use the compatible node and npm versions. Below is the npm and node version we are using

/vagrant/blockchain-explorer$ node -v
v12.16.2
/vagrant/blockchain-explorer$ npm -v
6.14.4

We were following the Explorer setup based on the Readme doc from the below URL. Done the DB setup successfully but while running the ./make.sh install,it is providing ENOENT errors which we assume it shouldn't with the above compatible versions we are using. Do we need to check any other prerequisites other than the above. Please advise

https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer

Answer (score 0):

Code error:"ENOENT" says that there was no entry file/directory.
While configuring  config.json with your network configuration, you might be missing or mis-configured some parameters.Make sure you have all key,certs and pem's routed correctly(path) in config.json.